# Can't get native messaging to work in Chrome Extension

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

Hope you can help me. I need to call an executable jar from an Chrome-Extension. By research I found https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging is the way to go.

So I first edited the manifest of my extension and added:

```
"permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
```

I can see in the Extensions overview, that the permission is granted.

As I am operating on Windows I added a Registry-Key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\myextension
with:
C:\path\to\myextension.json

the "myextension.json" contains:

```
{
  "name": "myextension",
  "description": "my extension",
  "path": "myextension.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://[key]/"
  ]
}
```

the myextension.bat contains:

```
@echo off
cd %windir%\system32
start calc.exe
```

(for testing just wanted to start the calculator)

in the js of my extension I try to call it by this:

```
var port = null;
var hostName = "myextension";
[...]
$(this).children(".abc").click(function() {
            //alert("test");
            port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
            alert(port);
            message = {"text": "nachricht"};
            port.postMessage(message);
          });
```

But nothing happens. The first alert "test" would be executed. But other than that nothing happens.

I really don't know how to debug it, because I don't get any feedback by executing it. Hope you can help me.

/edit
Just saw that I get:
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)"
at:

```
port = chrome.extension.connectNative(hostName);
```

or

```
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
```

/edit 2
Ok, now I got it to work when I use a button in the browser with: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.extension.connectNative('fbehost'); 
});`

But when I want to call it from a button in the website it doesn't work:

```
$(this).children(".abc").click(function() { 
  alert("Test"); 
  port = chrome.extension.connectNative("fbehost"); 
});
```

The alert works, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Try to give double backslashes for the registry key `C:\\path\\to\\myextension.json`. Other than that, I don't see any issue

Comment: Ok, now I got it to work when I use a button in the browser with:
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.extension.connectNative('fbehost');
});
But when I want to call it from a button in the website it doesn't work:
$(this).children(".abc").click(function() {
        alert("Test");
        port = chrome.extension.connectNative("fbehost");
      });
The alert works, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Aah you didn't tell us that the JS was in fact a content script. I thought it was a popup script. Content scripts cannot use all of the `chrome.` API, you should use message passing to a background script and then use the background script to connect to the native app

Comment: Now it works but I have a different problem. I posted it as a new question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500361/receiving-native-messages-from-chrome-in-java)