# Receiving native messages from Chrome in Java

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to get native messaging between a chrome extension and a Java program to work.
After some struggling I now can open my Java program with:

```
var port = chrome.extension.connectNative('fbehost');
port.postMessage({ text: "Hello, my_application" });
```

But I don't know how I can read the message send from my extension. I created a program which opens a simple JFrame with a textarea. As it says in the documentation that native messaging communicates with stdin and stdout, I tried to get the message with:

```
while(true) {
  try {
    input=br.readLine();
    tf.setAreaText(input);
  } catch(Exception e) {
  }
}
```

Also tried it with:

```
System.in.read()
```

The jar gets executed but the textarea stays empty. I can't find any information on the internet how to get the data in Java. Can you help me?

Comment: The first 4 bytes of the message indicate the length.  Are you reading those?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get any native messaging to work in Google Chrome recently. I remember reading somewhere that a semi-recent update appeared to prevent compatibility between Java and Chrome for native messaging. Best of luck.